# Question about NPN BJT transistor

Tags: voltage, transistors, current, bjt

I'm a bit curious about this thing. I know in NPN BJT transistor, current flows from collector to emitter since the emitter usually connected to the ground (please correct me if I'm wrong). What I want to ask is, in the worst case (assuming severe transistor failure,) is it possible for current to flow from emitter to collector(assuming that the collector have lower potential or connected to ground) and the emitter have higher potential compared to the collector?

Comment: FYI: Saying "ground" only complicates your question. A transistor doesn't know what "ground" is. All you need to ask is, "Can current flow from emitter to collector?" Andy Aka's answer says, "Yes, it can."

Answer (score 2):

> *in the worst case (assuming severe transistor failure), is it possible for current to flow from emitter to collector*

You don't need to assume transistor failure for this to happen. If you swap emitter and collector terminals, you will get an operational device but, it's β will not be as high as a normal connection. However, it will saturate to a lower emitter-collector voltage when driven hard and, occasionally, I've seen engineers do this (despite it looking a little odd).

Comment: I see, thanks for the answer!

Comment: to prevent this event, can i simply add a diode or does there exist other component to do such?

Comment: Like Andy writes: "You don't need to assume transistor failure for this to happen" so there's nothing you need to do to "solve" this as it will not be an issue provided you use the transistor properly (not exceed its maximum ratings). There is nothing to "solve" so don't try to! (Don't worry, it is typical for beginners to try and solve all kinds of non-issues.)

Comment: @AgustinusYudhistira You need to be totally clear about your circuit and explain what it is intended to do. I cannot mind-read on Mondays.

Comment: @Andy aka - fascinating.  In that configuration are you talking about forward-biasing the base-emitter junction and then passing current from emitter to collector (for an NPN) or just swapping the collector and emitter (which seems like a pointless way of making a bipolar work less well)?

Comment: @Frog You should try it on a breadboard and learn that it is true. If you dive into how BJTs are constructed: N-P-N you'll know they're symmetrical. The diffference between collector and emitter is their doping concentrations (the emitter has a higher doping). So the swapping emitter-collector still gives a working transistor but with a smaller beta because of the lower doping in the collector.

Comment: I'm talking about forward biasing the base-collector junction and yes, that means swapping E and C and yes, it is fairly pointless given that beta reduces dramatically with the only benefit being a significantly lower saturation voltage but, some folk have done it and, to them (when they did it) it probably wasn't pointless. However, in the modern world with the prevalence of MOSFETs I doubt it could ever now be justified.

Comment: @Andy aka i intend to use an optocoupler to isolate my microcontroller from high voltage with an optocoupler. I connect the collector with Analog Output in arduino and the emmiter of the optocoupler to the gate in the MOSFET. In case there are a MOSFET failure(The high voltage from drain manage to go through drain (please clarify me if it's possible or not possible)), does the optocoupler will protect my microcontroller from the high voltage?(arduino in this case, High voltage i use is 300V DC). Here is my schematic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyZ6W.png

Comment: @ Bimpelrekkie - I should and I shall.  However a few words of explanation serves the whole community well.  “Mankind is remarkable not only for its ability to learn from the mistakes of others, but also for it’s apparent disinclination to do so.” - Douglas Adams

Comment: @AgustinusYudhistira The opto-coupler will protect your micro in a direct sense but, it might cause problems with V2 and, that in turn may cause supply problems with your micro and end up burning that micro.

Comment: @Andyaka do you have any suggestion how can i protect the V2? because the V2 supply is the analog output from the arduino and i intend to protect the micron

Comment: What analogue output are you referring to? Is it a pin output from the arduino?

Comment: @Andyaka yes it's the output pin from arduino (the digital pin with ~)

Comment: Then that pin will be highly susceptible to failure should the MOSFET fail short circuit and cause the opto to do likewise @AgustinusYudhistira

Comment: @Andyaka do you have anny suggestion on the circuit design to overcome the problem? I tried to use zener diode to lower the voltage and diode to block the reverse current, will this prevent or minimalize the damage?

Comment: No, I don't have any suggestion and we have drifted far away from your original question now so, I suggest you raise a new question and get others involved in suggesting a solution @AgustinusYudhistira - this is a Q and A site and not a teaching forum; you ask a question and somebody answers it. OK a little leeway is given for follow-up questions but, we have gone past this point now .

Comment: Note for readers following this topic: As suggested, the OP has now asked a follow-on question here: "[Question about microcontroller protection from high voltage](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/573183/question-about-microcontroller-protection-from-high-voltage)"